# How is security ensured in hash functions where NULL bytes are not present?

Tags: c, cryptography, encryption

I was thinking about this problem to myself previously, and came up with the question:

"Theoretically, isn't it possible that a hash function of say, X random bytes, when hashed, would be considered vulnerable since NULL bytes in any character array would be interpreted as the end of a string in C? And therefore as an attacker we may ignore that character (and possibly others) within our initial string to brute force?"

Sorry if I'm not very clear on this.

Comment: You can't blame a totally unrelated hash function if you're treating a fixed-length buffer as 0-terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of hash functions is typically a fixed-length array of bytes (or machine words); it should be interpreted as a fixed-length array, not as a zero-delimited string.

The solution is to use `memcmp(3)` in your code instead of `strcmp(3)`.

Comment: Ahhhh! Ok. Silly me, why didn't I think of that?! I suppose strcmp() is also vulnerable to timing attacks anyway. Doh!

Comment: @malfy You can also have a timing attack with memcmp if the algorithm exits early when it finds a mismatch.  See http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/

Answer (score 3):

Hash functions do not produce string (character based) output. They produce (fixed-length) byte arrays. You can convert that to Base64 or Base16 if you want, then you have a string (which will never contain a null byte, just `00`).